# how to dynamically declare a 2-d array in c using type: int(*)[ ]?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have tried using int**(**pointer to a pointer)** and int*[](**array of pointers**) but i am unable to perform the task with **pointer to an array**.How can we use **pointer to an array** and **malloc** function to create an 2-d array in c.

**Please provide a sample code:)**

Comment: Exactly what difficulty have you encountered?  Array types are not different from other types with respect to dynamic allocation.  You declare a pointer of appropriate type, and assign the result of an appropriate `malloc()` call to it.  How about *you* providing some code to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *allocateMemory2DArray(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    int (*array)[x][y];

    array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    return array;
}
```

5d array

```
void *allocateMemory5DArray(size_t x, size_t y, size_t v, size_t q, size_t r)
{
    int (*array)[x][y][z][q][r];

    array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So let’s start from the ground up.

The typical way to dynamically allocate an N-element array of `T` (for some arbitrary `T`) is

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N ); // sizeof *p == sizeof (T)
```

This allocates enough space for N objects of type `T`, with `p` pointing to the first element

```
   T *        T
   +–––+      +–––+
p: |   |–––––>|   | p[0]
   +–––+      +–––+
              |   | p[1]
              +–––+
               ...
              +–––+
              |   | p[N-1]
              +–––+
```

Now, replace `T` with an array type - `R [M]`:

```
R (*p)[M] = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

This allocates enough space for N objects of type `R [M]` - IOW you’ve allocated an NxM array of `R`.  `p` still points to the first element, it’s just that in this case the first element is an array in itself.

```
   R (*)[M]    R [M]    
   +–––+       +–––+
p: |   |––––––>|   | p[0][0]
   +–––+       + - +
               |   | p[0][1]
               + - +
                ...
               + – + 
               |   | p[0][M-1]
               +––—+
               |   | p[1][0]
               + – +
               |   | p[1][1]
               + - +
                ...
               + – +
               |   | p[1][M-1]
               +–––+
                ...
               + – +
               |   | p[N-1][M-1]
               +–––+
```

You’d index into `p` like any regular 2d array.

You can extend this to higher-dimensioned arrays - replace `R` with another array type like `Q [L]`:

```
Q (*p)[M][L] = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

This allocates space for an NxMxL array, and again you’d index into it like any 3d array `p[i][j][k]`.

The semantics are exactly the same in every case - you’re allocating space for N objects, it’s just that the types of the objects are different.