# gcc Strange -O0 code generation. Simple malloc. Pointer to multidimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Very simple code:

```
void *allocateMemory5DArray(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, size_t q, size_t r)
{
    int (*array)[x][y][z][q][r];

    array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    return array;
}
```

The -O0 `gcc` needs 296bytes of the stack and the generated code is > 180 lines long.
Can anyone explain the rationale behind it?

Other compilers (except clang) also generate strange code, but not as strange as `gcc` :)

https://godbolt.org/z/1zx4YE

Comment: What is the problem? Optimized assembly looks fine. "-O0" is used only for fast compilation and debugging.

Comment: @tstanisl no problem - curiosity only. I do not ask what for the `-O0` is. Please focus on the question

Comment: Simpler: https://godbolt.org/z/T3zoMP . By varying the number of [x] it seems like O(n^2) code generation.

Comment: @PaulHankin it came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761774/how-to-dynamically-declare-a-2-d-array-in-c-using-type-int when I have noticed this strange behaviour

Comment: I think it's doing something for each dimension of the array it's computing the size (which is writes onto the stack), but for dimension i it recomputes the sizes of the lower dimensions. So it's computing something like `x`, `xy`, `xyz`, `xyzq`, `xyzqr` (with 10 muls rather than 4). The generated code does some "sub 1" too, so it's slightly more complicated than this, but I guess this is something like what's happening.

Comment: Note my example above shows that it's nothing to do with `malloc`.

Comment: @PaulHankin my guess was that it related to the possible large size of the array so I have limited the indexes to unsigned char which will result in max 1Tbytes which fits in the `size_t` type. But it did not change the situation significantly https://godbolt.org/z/57Mqa8

Comment: You could eliminate noise by reducing code to 'typedef arr_t[x][y][z][q][r]; return sizeof(arr_t);'

Comment: @tstanisl really ? https://godbolt.org/z/4dMdcT. So it is not the truth. But again even if - I am not asking "how to suppress the noise?" I do know how. If you want to participate - please focus on the question

Comment: My example godbolt.org/z/T3zoMP doesn't use malloc, doesn't need sizeof.

Comment: indeed. It looks that using a value of variable of variably-modified type is enough to trigger this behaviour.

Comment: Could you post a link, once you have reported it to gcc's bugzilla?

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour also happens with VLAs and Clang also generates a shorter code than GCC.

Although the generated code by GCC is longer, `-O0` has the [fastest compilation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Optimization-Levels.html) time (and apparently that's the fastest for GCC), the assembly code is not optimised but we didn't ask for that. When `-O1`, GCC sacrifices time by optimisation and the generated code is quite similar to clang.

---

There are differences between Clang and GCC regarding VLAs. The first one doesn't support VLAs in structures, the reasons:

- is tricky to implement
- the extension is completely undocumented
- the extension appears to be rarely used

Clang is happy with C-99 VLAs, but that's all. GCC 4.1 (consider that C99 was "substantially completely supported" with GCC 4.5 ) generates a similar (small) [size](https://godbolt.org/z/rWo5b9):

```
   ...
    mov     %rax, QWORD PTR [%rbp-56]
    mov     %rdx, QWORD PTR [%rbp-48]
    mov     %rcx, QWORD PTR [%rbp-40]
    mov     %rsi, QWORD PTR [%rbp-32]
    mov     %rdi, QWORD PTR [%rbp-24]
    ...
```

However, with GCC 4.8, the code gets larger. [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) file doesn't say anything about changes regarding VLAs which is weird considering the clear differences in the generated code.

[Status of C99 features in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) indicates that there were "Various corner cases fixed in GCC 4.5" related to VLAs. However, [4.5 changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) says nothing. Surprisingly, assembly is slighly different in 4.4 but not in 4.5.

It looks like Clang's reasons regarding VLAs in structs were very accurate and in some cases they may be extended to the whole VLA feature.

---

This poor behaviour is well-known. Linux's kernel is free of them in the name of [performance:](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=02361bc77888)

```
   Buffer allocation |  Encoding throughput (Mbit/s)
 ---------------------------------------------------
  on-stack, VLA      |   3988
  on-stack, fixed    |   4494
  kmalloc            |   1967
```

which is also good news for CLang builders.

Comment: The goal of -O0 is not necessarily the fastest compilation time, it happens regularly that -O1 is actually faster.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Agree that -O1 may be faster (IMO under certain circumstances), but [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Optimization-Levels.html) is categorical: "-O0 generates unoptimized code but has the fastest compilation time" and "-O1 optimizes reasonably well but does not degrade compilation time significantly" . Anyway, I edit the answer to provide similar info to the official one, thanks for that.

Comment: Bounty has been automatically granted, but this answer does not answer my question.